# differences between SSRS 2016 and Report Builder 2016

Tags: ssrs

I would like to know the differences between SSRS 2016 and Report Builder 2016
which one can be use for implementing AD security

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) is a server-based platform for hosting reports. Report builder is client tool that may be used to create reports to deploy to SSRS. As such, you would use SSRS to manage security on for the reports that you may have deployed with Report Builder.